# Erro em função de atualização no Python

Tags: python

Eu estou desenvolvendo um arquivo install.py que servirá como alternativa para instalar e criar executável de qq programa de forma simples e facil. Estou com dificuldade na função de atualização, eu chego a baixar a atualização do git mas não consigo copiar/mover para a pasta principal, os arquivos por algum motivo que desconheço, passam a serem restritos e também tornam-se executáveis. Funciona no Python2 e Python3, estou usando Linux para os testes.

Segue minha tentativa, dicas e aprimoramentos também são bem vindas:

```
def checkVersions():
    cv = getCurrentVersion() #Função que apenas retorna a versão instalada
    lv = checkLastVersion() #Função que apenas retorna a versão do git
    root = getPath() #Retorna o caminho até a pasta atual
    if (cv < lv):
        print ('Você tem a versão ' + str(cv) + ', enquanto a mais recente é a versão ' + str(lv) + '.')
        resp = input('Há uma versão mais recente desse aplicativo, deseja atualizar?(s/n)\n')
        if (resp == 'n'):
            pass
        elif (resp == 's'):
            import subprocess
            print('Atualizando para versão ' + str(lv) + '...')

            try:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(['git','--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                print(proc.stdout.readlines())
            except OSError as error:
                print (error)
                print ('Git não instalado, deseja instalar para atualizar?(s/n)')
                if (resp == 'n'):
                    print ('Atualização cancelada.')
                    return
                elif (resp == 's'):
                    os.system('sudo apt-get install git')
                else:
                    print ('Opção invalida, atualização negada.')
                    return

            currentFolder = '/'.join(getPath().split('/')[:-1])
            os.chdir(currentFolder)

            os.mkdir(Repo + '-tmp')

            currentFolder = currentFolder + '/' + Repo + '-tmp'
            os.chdir(currentFolder)

            os.system("git clone https://github.com/{user}/{repo}.git".format(user = User, repo = Repo))

            tmpFolder = currentFolder + '/' + Repo + '/'

            print ('Copiando os novos arquivos...')
            # O Problema está dentro desse try
            try:
                for files in os.listdir(root):
                    if os.path.isfile(files):
                        if files != 'install.py':
                            os.system('sudo rm -f ' + root + '/' + files)
                #           os.remove(files)
                    else:
                        os.system('sudo rm -rf ' + root + '/' + files)
                #       rmtree(files)

                for files in os.listdir(tmpFolder):
                    src = os.path.join(tmpFolder, files)
                    dst = os.path.join(root, files)
                    if os.path.isfile(files):
                        if files != 'install.py':
                            copy2(src, dst)
                    else:
                        copyFolder(tmpFolder, root)

                changePerm(root)

            except OSError as error:
                os.chdir(root)
                os.system('sudo rm -rf ' + currentFolder)
                print (error)
                print ('Erro ao atualizar')
                return

            os.chdir(root)
            os.system('sudo rm -rf ' + currentFolder)
            print('Atualização para versão ' + str(lv) + ' concluida!')
        else:
            print('Resposta inválida...')
            checkVersions()
```

Funções complementares:

```
def copyFolder(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if item != 'install.py':
                copy2(s, d)

def changePerm(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        os.chmod(r, 0o777)
```

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar mais informações sobre o erro. O que falha? Qual a mensagem de erro? No fim, quais arquivos não foram copiados? Em que linha ocorre o problema? Tem o traceback completo do erro?

Comment: Se o problema está dentro do `try`, pode ser que o `try` esteja "escondendo" a mensagem de erro. Retire o `try` para que o erro seja exibido completamente e então cole-o na pergunta.

Comment: Mas eu disse o erro, não consigo copiar/mover os arquivos baixados para a pasta original sem alterar suas permissões. Só apontei o try que é onde está a parte onde apago e copio os arquivos. Não aparece um erro na tela em si, mas o resultado final como disse não é o esperado.

Comment: como assim não consegue? Os arquivos são copiados mas as permissões não são? Quais as permissões iniciais dos arquivos? Quais permissões terminam no arquivo final? `shutil.copy2` deveria copiar as permissões... tem certeza que o sistema de arquivos de destino suporta as permissões que você está tentando copiar?

Comment: Tente criar um [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que a gente possa reproduzir o problema e descobrir o que está errado